# Add an index to duplicate elements of a string list in C#

Tags: c#, duplicates

I need help with an algorithm that will add an index to the duplicate elements in a string list in C#.

i.e.

```
A, B, C, D, A, B, E, F, A
```

will become

```
A, B, C, D, A (1), B (1), E, F, A (2)
```

Comment: I wish someone would do this with LINQ

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var strings = new string[] { "A", "B", "C", "D", "A", "B", "E", "F", "A" };

Dictionary<string, int> counts = new Dictionary<string, int>();
for (int i = 0; i < strings.Length; ++i)
{
    if (counts.ContainsKey(strings[i]))
        strings[i] = string.Format("{0} ({1})", strings[i], counts[strings[i]]++);
    else
        counts.Add(strings[i], 1);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
Dictionary<char,int> counts = new Dictionary<char,int>();

foreach (char c in myCharArray)
{
if (counts.Keys.Contains(c))
{
counts[c]++;
myOutputList.Add(c + "(" + counts[c] + ")");
}
else 
{
counts.Add(c,0);
}
```

}

Added:

What I'm basically doing is going through the array one character at a time. I'm keeping a count of 'times I've seen each character' in the dictionary - which I increment every time I see a new one.

When I see one which I've seen already - I add the number in brackets as requested.

Answer (score 1):

Using Lamba/LINQ

```
  string x = "A, B, C, D, A, B, E, F, A";
  x = x.Replace(" ", "").Replace(",", ""); //Remove the spaces and commas
  var l = x.Select((v, i) => String.Format("{0}({1})", v, x.Substring(0, i).Count(c => c.Equals(v))));

  var s = l.Select(c=>c.Replace("(0)","")).ToArray();
  string result = String.Join(", ", s);
```

Comment: Very good, it has helped me to do it with columns in an array (in the same way as the column names in Excel, to use in OpenXML)



            `IEnumerable<string> names = new[] { "Columna", "Columna", "Nombre", "Columna", "Apellidos", "Columna" };
            names = names.Select((columnName, index) =>
            {
                string duplicatedIndex = names.Take(index).Count(item => item == columnName).ToString();
                return string.Format("{0}{1}", columnName, duplicatedIndex == "0" ? string.Empty : duplicatedIndex);
            }).ToList();`